# VS Code cant find python even though it detects interpreter , it runs in terminal but not in output

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I installed Anaconda and VS Code in my F drive. After starting VS code it can automatically find my python interpreter > python 3.11.3 ('base:conda) f:\Anaconda\python.exe but cant run it giving error >'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

whereas on Terminal it runs with the text >G:\AI_Chilla> & F:/Anaconda/python.exe

Answer (score 0):

This issue is usually caused by your Python not being added to the system environment variables.

You can open your system environment variable.

[image]

Double-click **Path** and then click "New" and add the path to your Anaconda installation directory (in your case, it's `F:\Anaconda`).